# How can I move a question to another SE site that isn't on this list?

Tags: support, migration

I see I can flag my own question and click as off-topic to be able to move it to another site but I only see a few sites in the list:

[image]

In my case, I want to move a question from **[Super User](http://www.superuser.com/)** to the **[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)** Stack Exchange site.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regular users are only able to vote to migrate questions to sites on the pre-defined list. These sites are specifically chosen based on what sorts of off-topic questions are typically asked on Super User. If you need a question migrated to a different SE site not on the list, please flag the post for moderator attention, and state which site you'd like it moved to. Moderators can migrate any question to any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: If this were the case, then the discussion [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2774/apple-se-as-off-topic-migration-path) would have gone differently. It's both *diamonds' expectations* where questions are migrated to, as well as their expectations which options aren't misused by people able to vote.

Comment: @DanielBeck that is true - it's a combination of the statistics of where questions typically need to be migrated, and what migration paths make sense for other reasons. Some paths, such as Ask Different and Ask Ubuntu haven't been enabled because of the likelihood of users mistakenly migrating questions there which are on-topic and acceptable for Super User.