# Apple questions: To iMigrate, or not to iMigrate?  

Tags: discussion, apple

Lately I've noticed that some questions about Apple's products have been migrated to the https://apple.stackexchange.com/ web site.

Should all Apple questions be migrated to that site?  Or is there a specific criteria?

In looking at that site, I see questions about iPhones, iPods, iTunes, and MacBook computers, plus other various Apple-related topics.

Comment: Sometimes even the diamonds make [mistakes](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/icloud-and-document-data-syncing) in migrating on-topic Apple questions. Doesn't mean it's policy. And the "everything Apple needs to go" attitude [some users](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1631/it-annoys-me-that-theres-an-apple-se-but-so-many-apple-questions-on-su) have is [the reason we don't have the Apple.SE migration path](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2774/apple-se-as-off-topic-migration-path).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Our official policy is as follows:

- Questions which are *on topic* for Super User stay here, unless the *original question asker* requests they be migrated.
- Off-topic questions for Super User (things about iPhones, iPods, etc.) should be flagged for migration.

For more details, see [Is it okay to inform users to stop promoting Apple.SE when a question is fine to stay here?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to/2968#2968)

Comment: Thanks, your explanation (and the answer you linked to) is very helpful.

Comment: In commenting on the question, I noticed [this topic](http://superuser.com/questions/346904/icloud-and-document-data-syncing?noredirect=1) was deleted. What's going on there? It was perfectly on topic here, but my flag for migration back wasn't acted on. Now it's even deleted?!

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  Post a new question about that in meta and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm guessing it was migrated because iCloud is more of an applies-to-apple-products thing, and thus they don't want to send it back now. Not entirely sure though. It's still [over on Apple.SE though](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/icloud-and-document-data-syncing); it isn't entirely deleted.

Comment: @nhinkle No reason to delete and make the link back to SU a 404 for all non-10k+ users.

Comment: After migration, the stub is automatically deleted after 30 days @dan

Comment: Thanks @random , but wouldn't it make sense to also remove the link on the destination site to the original site?

Comment: It would, and since it affects the whole network, it might be a good feature request on Meta to have the scheduled task remove the link back since you might as well chop both arms off @dan

Comment: @random They make sense though: If you have 10k+ rep, you can (and should be able to) see the original, then deleted question. So only users with below 10k rep on the question's original site should get the link back. *But* it's probably not possible for e.g. Apple.SE to determine your SU rep to find out whether to display the link. And if that's not possible, it's best to leave the link in. Even if determining your rep on another site was possible easily, since you don't necessarily have an account on the destination site, the system cannot know whether to display the link.