# Please vote on proposed changes to our policy on tablet computers

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, scope

We recently asked [how you feel about questions regarding Windows 8 on ARM](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4885/how-are-we-going-to-deal-with-windows-8-on-arm). After looking through the answers and comments there, and some lengthy discussion amongst the moderators, we've come up with the following possible changes to our policies on tablets.

As the nature of computing changes, so should we. Increasingly, super users like ourselves have more than just a desktop and a laptop. Furthermore, the line between "computer" and "device" is blurring. Nevertheless, with any of the options below, we will naturally continue our policy of requiring high-quality, practical, answerable questions. None of the suggested changes would allow for open-ended app recommendations, purchasing suggestions, etc.

Here are the options we have come up with:

> - **Continue the status quo.** No tablet questions allowed, unless it's running a desktop operating system. Windows on ARM questions
>     would not be permitted, but Windows 8 on x86-64 hardware would be
>     allowed.
> - **Allow appropriate tablet questions**, but not actively encourage iOS and Android. Basically they will be treated like Ubuntu and OS X are treated right now.
> - **Allow any tablet questions.** Treat tablets like any other computer.
> - **Make an exception specifically for Windows 8 on ARM**, to avoid confusion for users. Questions about other tablets would still be
>     off-topic, but we would allow WOA questions since the operating system
>     is similar enough to regular Windows 8.

If any of the options for broadening the scope is chosen, we will put the new policy into effect shortly, and give it a discrete "trial run" in advance of the Windows 8 launch. At the time of the Windows 8 launch, we expect an influx of tablet questions, so we should have determined by then whether we're OK with the changes or not.

Initially, this will be *quiet*. We may start allowing tablet questions of some form, but will not *advertise* that. Once we determine if it seems to be working, we can make an official decision and make that information available via the blog and other sources.

Please vote on the options below. If you have commentary, please leave it under the original question or one of the polling options. The purpose of this question is to serve as a poll, so we'd like to avoid adding additional answers beyond the choices given here.

---

<sub>Please note that this post is meant to be a means for the Super User moderators to gauge the general feelings of the community on this issue. Votes on the options here do not necessarily reflect the final decision that will be made. The moderation team reserves the right to make a decision which may not directly correspond with the options laid out or voted upon here.</sub>

Comment: I think this should be mention on the blog as well.

Comment: What's the difference between `Appropriate tablet questions` and `Exception for Windows 8 on ARM`?

Comment: @DanielBeck iPad, Android, WebOS, etc. tablet questions could be allowed within reason, but we'd encourage them to ask on other sites (where they exist).

Comment: Are we only counting upvotes? Or are we using the sum as shown?

Comment: @iglvzx this is more of an opinion poll than a "please cast an official ballot to determine the absolute policy decision." As such, you can interpret it as you like.

Comment: _Super User ... is not about ... _electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer_. I think this is key. Do we expect windows ARM (or insert-tablet-here) to be **the computer** that these other devices interface with?

Comment: @JeremyW if we change our scope, we can change our FAQ to reflect that. Don't feel obligated by what's presently in the FAQ when thinking about this question.

Comment: @nhinkle certainly it could be changed. Many tablets don't allow electronic devices to interface directly (such as printers, headsets, portable electronic gadgets, even phones) if the ARM/x86 tablets allow such things then I think the bit about being the computer that other devices interface with is helpful for limiting our scope.

Comment: What's the current status regarding mobile devices that run Linux-which-is-not-Android?  e.g. Symbian?  The set of questions on an uncrippled Linux device has very little to do with the CPU architecture.

Comment: @BenVoigt if it's about liniux, it's probably fine. If it's about the phone though, then we're not really equipped to answer it.

Comment: *zynic rant*: I believe that if "we" or more like you start allowing "appropriate tablet questions" while disencouraging iOS and Android the scope-reduction will become even more ridiculous. If you want to refer them to the sister-sites, We might as well split up SU into windows & linux user dot com and close down SU; and everyone will be referred to the community with their ecosystem.

What the hell would be so bad about having ios, android, os-x as tags here and closing down or redirecting from the sister-sites?

**Macs are computers, tablets and smartphones are, it is *that* simple.**

Comment: Should this still be Featured?

Comment: @MatthewRead probably not. The featured tag is supposed to expire after 2 weeks, but apparently didn't.

Comment: @AnnaLear For Super User, any FAQ change *is* a feature request.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

## Allow appropriate tablet questions

Vote for this option if you believe we should allow tablet questions, but shouldn't actively encourage iOS or Android questions. We would update our FAQ to mention all the relevant sister-sites: Unix, Ubuntu, Apple and Android as great places to ask questions about their respective ecosystems, while allowing them on SU as well. Furthermore, we would mention this in the announcement blog post, to make it clear that we support our sister-sites as well.

Under this option in particular, tablet questions would be closely watched during the trial phase, to make sure that they are meeting our typical quality standards. Moderators and users would have to use discretion in determining whether particular tablet questions are appropriate, but we would in general tolerate questions pertaining to these devices.

Comment: For all the skeptics, I'd view this as Facebook.SO. Sure, there's some awful stuff in there, but we all understand why we need it. Given our current style of moderation, I don't see why tablets would cause any problems we can't deal with. So let's just give it a shot!

Comment: So what would this entail for "phones" / "smartphones", which basically run off the same operating systems?

Comment: @slhck _personally_, I think smartphones should still stay out of this.

Comment: Definitely not. **A site's policy should make sense in isolation.** "We no longer accept this because there's a more specific site for it" is a really bad response, and topic overlap is tolerated and actively encouraged on the SE network. Quoting [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), *attempting to micromanage what’s on-topic in order to avoid overlap with other sites or simply drive away users seen as undesirable* is **undesired behavior**. If we accept a question for one device, we should accept the equivalent for a similar device.

Comment: @DanielBeck I feel like if anything, this option best satisfies your point. We'd _allow_ iPad and Android questions if people really wanted to ask them here and if they were _good_ questions, but we'd make sure they knew that other sites were available.

Comment: I still think that the iPad questions should be shuffled to [apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) and the Android to [android](http://android.stackexchange.com/) as the users questions will probably be answered quicker, recieve a larger applicable audience and probably have a higher accept rate.

Comment: @HaydnWVN Choosing a particular site is the user's right. We had this in the past with Ubuntu and OS X as well and we certainly will not make our policy to accept *questions about computer hardware, unless they're from Apple, and computer software, unless they're Linux*.

Comment: Update: I've edited the answer in response to Daniel's comment.

Comment: There is a clear distinction missing here:  A tablet that "tries really hard to act like a computer", isn't a computer.  While a computer that happens to have a tablet input panel, is a computer.  The user can administrate/"be the superuser" of the later.  The user can only use the former.  To discard this distinction, I think, would make for bad policy.  If this site is supposed to be about asking superuser questions to other superusers, then tablets that don't give the user superuser access are "off topic".

Comment: @killermist I strongly disagree with this notion. We're not the CS Theory of computers, so we don't only cater to questions by so called experts that have superuser access. I want SU to be a site where I can point my GF to, to get an answer, rather than having to solve each of her problems in person.

Comment: so @killermist my question on getting something done in MS Office must be offtopic because my computer doesn't have Admin privileges? the site name doesn't signify that all computers must have superuser access to be fit for the site. I don't see how admin access makes a clear distinction

Comment: We all have different opinions.  I'm not trying to be argumentative.  I'm just stating mine, and supplying my backing logic, which you are perfectly fine to disagree with.  The question is trying to gauge where the community is, and I'm just trying to be honest.

Comment: @IvoFlipse if this gains enough momentum (as I assume it will) is there an option to have something similar to Facebook.SO?  Like a Tablet.SU?

Comment: @KronoS I don't see a real need honestly, if only because we're still too small compared to SO to warrant subdomains like that

Comment: I think this is acceptable, but I'd encourage moving these topics to more appropriate sites when possible to continue. Closing them when they don't have a home or closing them without moving them should stop though.

Comment: Retracting my earlier opinion, **+1**. We *need* to accept tablet computer questions simply because these are rapidly becoming *the computer* for many people. Regarding my earlier doubts that this will mean that tablet computer topics will only be second class on SU: The moderators already wrote in chat that tablet computer questions will not be handled differently from today's Ubuntu or OS X questions, and that sounds reasonable, **creating a consistent and easy to understand policy** on what we consider on topic.

Comment: From the about page: "With your help, we can build good answers to every question a power user might have. No matter what operating system you choose, or what hardware you run it on, we can learn from each other." This statement actually goes more with "Allow any tablet questions", and I really don't see much differnce between these two answers except for attitude. I'll +1 this one because it's close enough, and the other is obviously not popular in the community.

Comment: @ivo "we should allow tablet questions, but shouldn't actively encourage iOS or Android questions" So if it's going to be de-facto Windows tablet, why not just *say* that? I think it's crazy to allow Android or iPad tablet questions on Super User at all, simply because they already have dedicated Stack Exchange sites and communities which will provide *far* better answers than SU. I struggle to think of any reason an experienced SU user, versed in Linux and OSX and Windows, would know anything at all about iOS or Android OS. Can't say that about Windows 8 tablets.

Comment: @Jeff The same could be said about Linux and OSX questions belonging on their respective sites. I don't **want** to take away any questions from Android or Apple, I just want a policy that will be easier to explain to people and doesn't require a slew of bullet points that arbitrarily excludes things.

Comment: In this case, I think I agree with @Ivo. We should not be trying to become The Place for iOS/Android questions, but if someone happens to ask a question about one of those here we shouldn't punish them for it.

Comment: @ivo so we let them *punish themselves* by asking a question that is very unlikely to get a good answer because it is being presented to the wrong audience? That's harmful to the site, and harmful to the user who asked the question. There is no iOS or Android expertise here. But Windows Surface is *based on previous and current versions of Windows*, it is not a different OS. That's why the knowledge transfers.

Comment: @ivo and this is a *very different* thing than Linux and OSX. iOS and Android are *totally different operating systems*, designed from scratch to run on devices that may or may not be computers, that have zero historical basis on this site. Whereas Windows 8, being Win32.. does.

Comment: @jeff I'd rather see how many users punish themselves, before punishing others by prematurely excluding them. We can't predict how these questions will be predicted, because there's no history of answers either. I'll be the first to admit our mistake if you turn out to be right, but I'd also prefer to first see if you do.

Comment: Also, its probably easier to talk about this on chat, than through a stream of comments

Comment: @JeffAtwood I'm curious what your stance is on Windows on ARM questions. It's not Win32, and there's no real historical context for those sorts of questions. That being said, it would be mighty confusing to users if we only allow Windows 8 questions if it's on x86-64 hardware.

Comment: @ivo if the community wants it, you can certainly try it as an experiment. But I want to go on record saying that this is kind of a "punish the user" decision you guys are making here, in the sense that you're allowing them to ask questions that have near-zero probability of getting good answers on Super User, based on the existing audience. Woe betide the poor user that asks an iPad question here "because it is allowed"; that can only end in tears.

Comment: Of course, if someone who does have superuser access on an iOS or Android system wants to ask a question about mostly-generic Darwin or Linux stuff ...

Comment: Perhaps each tablet OS deserves its own stack exhange?

Comment: @AlexNye Area 51 stack site has loads of interesting new and old site  proposals which never quite make it, i.e "Deserved = Sustainable". If there is sustainable and enthusiastic participation over there, only then is any new site proposal proven to be deserving.

Comment: Is it possible to list this in the "Ask a Question" page? I just incorrectly vote closed something because it says: * electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer, I counted a tablet as Electronic device.

Answer (score -1):

## Make an exception specifically for Windows 8 on ARM

Vote for this option if you believe we should make an exception specifically for Windows 8 on ARM. This would be done to avoid confusion for users, given the similarity between the "traditional" and "tablet-only" versions of Windows 8. Questions about other tablets would still be off-topic.

Comment: I'd think this might be a viable solution *unless* there was a windows phone SE site. I'd suggest that we'd insist these questions be tagged specifically [tag:windows8-rt] perhaps, both to avoid confusion and so we can migrate these easily.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek there [is a specific Windows Phone site](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), but a) Windows 8 isn't Windows Phone, and b) part of the problem here is that there'll be a lot of Windows 8 questions that could apply to _either_ type, and we want to avoid splitting them up. I agree that a `windows-rt` tag would be appropriate for questions that are _specific_ to the ARM version though, if we end up allowing them in one way or another.

Comment: We never cared about what other sites exist for a certain topic, and shouldn't start now. [Windows 8 on ARM does not run any of today's Windows software, so it's hardly more of a "real computer" than Android, iOS and Web OS devices](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4885/how-are-we-going-to-deal-with-windows-8-on-arm).

Comment: The underlying 'user' questions associated with Windows 8 on ARM will 90% apply to the x86 version of the OS. It's just what to do with those 10% of questions which may be specific to ARM, personally I think it would be silly to shuffle those off elsewhere. You'd seem to be dividing the Windows 8 tablet community.

Comment: @HaydnWVN that's basically why this whole thing came up, and you hit the nail in the head. It doesn't make sense to say "you can ask about Windows 8 Metro all you want. Unless it's running on ARM."

Comment: @nhinkle Actually, it does. We're already broadening question scope to make questions on topic. If the user only gets answers that don't apply to his particular situation, tough.

Comment: Isn't that the way it should work though? Flexible answers and solutions are easier than having flexible questions asked... As they won't be lol :)

Comment: This is a slippery slope argument (and not a good one). The user never really will get to act as a superuser on WinRT/ARM tablets because via hardware lock-in, Microsoft will be permanently seated as the absentee-landlord superuser of something the user just happens to own.  My simple rule of thumb, if the user isn't able to act as a superuser, then it isn't a superuser question.  And with MS the administrator/superuser of the hardware, the user can never be the superuser.

Comment: Are you a Super User within Office? There are plenty of questions left about a device without ever having to change the software

Comment: I formulated this thought well in the previous thread, so I'm just copying:  I know this will sound condescending, but there's nothing to do for it, so here goes. A user that can't distinguish between a Windows RT tablet and a Windows 8 computer is NOT acting as a superuser. That being said if THEY don't know what they have, then their questions are likely to confuse those trying to give them answers, because responders will first have to decipher what the question is in the first place. I don't advocate leaving them out in the cold. But, this isn't the right place for those questions.

Comment: @IvoFlipse Personally, I consider Office questions off-topic, I skip them immediately, both because they hold no interest for me, and because I probably wouldn't have an answer in the first place.  Maybe that's prejudicial of me, but questions regarding Office just don't seem "superusery" to me, and they aren't why I'm here.  I have administrated many machines over many years.  I've occasionally had just-user grade questions, but often they sharpened me as an administrator.  Office, doesn't sharpen anyone. (personal opinion)

Comment: @killermist However office questions are viable here, and that's the way that it's been.  The fact is, that Super User is a melting pot of topics that are allowed.  This was the idea from it's creation.  This doesn't mean we just allow anything, but we should be ready for the fact that there is going to be addition/subtractions as technology and other SE sites progress.

Comment: @killermist you need to get past the name of the site and realize that at the end of the day, we're a place to ask questions about computers. The people who _answer_ are usually "super users," but that doesn't mean we aren't a resource for everybody.

Comment: @nhinkle You may be right, but I guess that part of my concern is that these tablets aren't a computer, and will probably dilute the discussion even more, maybe leading to other users like myself progressively losing interest in SU and migrate in the directions of the more specific niches like Unix/Linux, Ubuntu, etc., which I think _could_ be detrimental to SU.  But, I'm just one guy that personally thinks that tablets are unequal to computers.

Comment: @killermist in the larger scope of things, I think the dilution will be minimal. We get ~200 questions/day. If we start getting 210 questions/day, 10 of which are tablet questions, it's not going to dilute it significantly.

Answer (score -8):

## Allow any tablet questions

Vote for this option if you believe we should treat tablets like other computers, and start allowing tablet questions for all platforms (within the bounds of what is considered a reasonable, on-topic question).

Comment: This is just ridiculous as it will create a bunch of fodder that we'll have to handle.

Comment: @KronoS I think this option is safely in the "not approved of" zone now.

Comment: It does not do any good to vote for this, but I think it is complete BS to be restricing users to such small areas, and requring people to hop all over the rest of stack exchange or the rest of the web to ask questions that do not fit into the microbe of allowances at superuser.  I fint it is a lot less restricting, more freedom and more humanly personable to be on a forum where communications, and free speeches are not confined to a little bubble.  While the experts and mods here are of high caliber, the freedom is the lowest of any user communications site on the web.

Answer (score -14):

## Continue the status quo

Vote for this option if you believe we should continue the current state of affairs. No tablet questions allowed, unless it's running a desktop operating system. Windows on ARM questions would not be permitted, but Windows 8 on x86-64 hardware would be allowed.

Comment: Doing this just ignores the problems that we're going to face.  A change needs to happen of some sort.

Comment: I would strongly consider having a tablet-specific version of superuser instead of integrating those questions here.

Comment: Why allow Windows 8 on x86-64  but not Windows on ARM ? ... what is the distinction between the two ?