# Are tablet questions off topic?

Tags: support

The FAQ says the following is on topic

> computer hardware,
>   computer software, or
>   personal and home computer networking

and this is not

> programming and software development,
>      video games or consoles,
>      websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
>      electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
>      issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
>      asking for a shopping or product recommendation,

Cell phones and smart phones are mentioned explicity, but tablets are not.

Are tablets are on or off topic and does the OS matter?

Comment: Might be relevant: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5045/please-vote-on-proposed-changes-to-our-policy-on-tablet-computers Pretty sure we have other existing questions on the topic. This was the best I could dig up right now :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated site for at least Android, but if the question is about software of hardware in general I think it's totally acceptable. Tablets are strictly speaking Von Neumann machines just as regular computers. They run similar software too.

Comment: Same for Apple though... Ha ha, SU is fine for Apple, Linux and Windows, but only poor Windows doesn't get it's own site! :)

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин _Tablets are strictly speaking Von Neumann machines just as regular computers. They run similar software too._ - How is that not true for _**any**_ smartphone?