# Migrating questions to the Ubuntu or Linux/Unix Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, migration

I just realised that there are Stack Exchange sites for Ubuntu and Linux/Unix.

Why aren't all the Linux/Unix/Debian etc questions on Super User getting migrated there?

Comment: Because they're on-topic here, so why should we migrate them away? See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1308/superuser-vs-unix-linux-vs-ubuntu and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1572/do-we-want-to-have-an-option-to-migrate-to-askubuntu . There's been similar discussion about Apple things as well, http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1631/it-annoys-me-that-theres-an-apple-se-but-so-many-apple-questions-on-su for example.

Comment: So there is nothing like migrate to the best scope?

Comment: And who defines "best scope"...? It's up to the *user* asking the question which of these communities they wish to approach. Just because someone has a question about their home server (running a flavour of Linux), it *doesn't* necessarily mean they want cramming in to a room full of Linux boffins...  Also, see my answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Questions are only migrated when there is a problem, specifically they need to be off-topic on the site on which they are posted, or if the user who asked the question specifically requests that it be moved.

Computer software and hardware are on-topic on SU - including Ubuntu, Linux, Unix, Mac, etc - so questions that are valid for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) are usually valid here as well (the obvious exception being iPhone, etc questions which are OK on AD, but not here).

The sites have different community spirits and different community goals, so it's important that if a user attempts to interact with one of these communities that we don't push them away. So if someone has made the effort to ask a valid question on SU, we will not automatically shunt it to another site.

Migrating a question can be damaging to the user experience of the owner and greatly increases the chance of the question being abandoned.

Finally, in the cases when we do migrate to these sites it's usually because the question hasn't received much attention locally and - more importantly - because the asker has requested that it be moved.

Comment: I've never seen an 'asker' request migration. Is that because it's done by flagging?

Comment: @pavium, those I've seen have usually been requested by flags, yes. And when I migrate on behalf of the OP I will add a comment saying that I'm doing so for that reason.

Comment: so this site is practically a garbage dump for everything and nothing... I have to admit that I do not like this (I know, nobody cares ;)  ). I'd liked the approach to collect specific topics at specific sites... everything good in the web will get corrupted when to many people know about it :(

Answer (score 2):

Cue my usual advice: what does this user self-identify as?

- A unix nut

or

- 'gee I love all my computers no matter what OS they run' enthusiast?

That will tell you which site they belong on.

Related:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/

Comment: It's a very good point Jeff. I've found that there's an uncanny way that questions *do* find themselves asked on the most appropriate site 95% of the time. I have no idea why this works, but it does seem to work.

Comment: most ubuntu users are not unix nuts and thats why au separated from the unix site .