# Flagging Questions as off-topic

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic, flagging

When flagging questions as off-topic, and we are given options to choose a site it should go to... What determines that list?  For example, if I see a question on SU that I think should belong on the [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) site, but all I see is:

> - is off topic, Questions on Super User are expected to generally
>     relate to computer software or computer hardware, within the scope
>     defined in the faq.
> - belongs on meta.superuser.com, discussion, support, and feature
>     requests for this site
> - belongs on stackoverflow.com, Q&A for professional and enthusiast
>     programmers
> - belongs on serverfault.com, Q&A for system administrators and
>     desktop support professionals
> - belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com, Q&A for power users of web
>     applications
> - belongs on gaming.stackexchange.com, Q&A for passionate videogamers
>     on all platforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The migration paths in the flag as off topic dialog are identical to those in the vote to close dialog which you have access to once you earn 3000 rep. Every site has its own meta first and up to four other migration paths determined by what was expected to be needed most frequently.

If you feel something needs migration to a site that isn't listed use the
`it needs ♦ moderator attention` → `other` option and write in the free text field where you think it should be going, and possibly why if it's not obvious. Moderators can migrate questions to any SE site.

Please note, however, that Apple based questions (and any other case where topics overlap such as Unix & Linux and AskUbuntu) will not normally be migrated to another site if they are on topic on Super User, unless the request is from the question owner and there's little value it keeping it here.

Comment: Why should Superuser cover Apple software and hardware if that is specifically what the Apple portion of SE is designed for?

Comment: Because it is still on topic here.

Comment: Because we have different user bases @wizlog. If someone asks an (on topic!) Apple question here why should we be saying "Excuse me, sorry, you should go stand over there with all the other Apple guys, *we don't want you here*." If they've come here to ask us a question that we have always supported - since way before the creation of Apple.SE - then we should be helping them. Also, have a look at what [I've said before](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644/migrating-questions-to-the-ubuntu-or-linux-unix-se-sites/2645#2645) on the topic.

Comment: @wizlog see our response on [Is it okay to inform users to stop promoting Apple.SE when a question is fine to stay here?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to/2968#2968)

Comment: Ah ha! I *knew* there was a better post somewhere, thanks @nhinkle I'll be starring that one for later.