# How can I request to move a question to a different Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, migration

[I have a question](https://superuser.com/questions/385389/eclipse-run-configurations) that would be better off on Stack Overflow, but I asked it here.

I've added an edit asking it to be moved, but it's still here.

How can I request for it to be moved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can flag your own question and ask a moderator to migrate the question to any other Stack Exchange site. Also, the community might see the question and vote for it to be moved - although this only allows for a few common migration paths.

In this case, I think your question could be applicable on either Super User (because it involves computer software) or Stack Overflow (because it involves development tools). In these cases, we tend [not to move questions](https://meta.superuser.com/a/2645/494), unless the asker requests it. So, in other words, if you'd prefer your question on Stack Overflow, flag it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question should **NOT** be moved to Stack Overflow. It doesn't have to do with programming, it has to do with the software Eclipse, and is on topic here.

You can usually have a question migrated by flagging a moderator for attention though, just by hitting flag, then Off topic, and pressing one of the indicated sites, or by adding it under "Other".

[image]

Comment: Note though that SO deals with *software tools commonly used by programmers* (see FAQ).

Comment: ... and users are free to choose a different site if they think it's more appropriate.