# Can I move/duplicate a question to another Stack site?

Tags: support, questions, stackexchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I request to move a question to a different Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4401/how-can-i-request-to-move-a-question-to-a-different-stack-exchange-site)

I have a question on this site that may as well work at, say, Ask Different. Is it possible to transfer my question to that site, or perhaps, duplicate it?

Comment: Please don't duplicate the question. Just flag it and tell us what site it should go to. Just make sure it's on-topic there :)