# site scope about file descriptors

Tags: discussion

I did [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/583157/how-to-check-which-process-is-using-a-given-file-descriptor) here a few minutes ago, then I tough it would probably be more in the scope of `Unix and Linux`.

Since super user have tags for I assume the question is on topic here, is it?
If not, why?

Comment: Just a quick reply: **Never** cross-post (posting the same question on multiple sites).

Comment: so I guess it would be better delete one of them...

Comment: Yes. The question is on-topic for [SU], as far as I'm concerned. Please pick one site and remove the question from the other. I'll write a proper answer soon :)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644/migrating-questions-to-the-ubuntu-or-linux-unix-stack-exchange-sites/2645#2645).

Comment: Even though it's not off-topic, since you chose not to remove either question and people are already spending time on it, I closed it as off-topic on SU now.

Comment: I had reported the question as duplicate in `Unix & Linux`

Comment: @RSFalcon7: Usually, you can delete your own question. However, you can't if someone already posted an answer and received an upvote for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, the question is perfectly on-topic for Super User. Although it should probably have the tags [file-descriptors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-descriptors) and [unix](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unix) (or, even better, the tag for the actual operating system you are using).

Overall, it's hard for me to get a grip on the question. Some more insights into ROOT might be helpful. After all, maybe someone who isn't familiar with the specific environment might still be able to find a solution if more context is provided.

That being said, please **never** post a question on multiple StackExchange sites at the same time. Users might invest their time into trying to solve your problem, only to come up with an answer identical to one that was provided on another site only minutes before they've come up with theirs.

This leads to people feeling like they've wasted their time and they might be disappointed. This is something we don't want to happen.

If you've posted a question a while ago, and it hasn't gotten any answers (or not much attention in general), you might want to join us in our chat room [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access) to see what a good cause of action might be. Or, if you've already have a good idea and want your question moved to another site, flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated to the site you like.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had just asked a [question](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6655/151431) about this post and was wondering why you considered in off topic. I see now that you don't (as Kronos also explained).

Comment: @terdon: Correct. I left [a comment](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6653/site-scope-about-file-descriptors/6654?noredirect=1#comment16997_6653) on the meta question here to specifically note this fact. In the future, I'll try to also leave a note in this regard on the question itself.