# Request to reopen question 151431

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/583157/151431) was closed as off topic but it is perfectly valid and on topic. The OP was not very clear and at first glance it might look like a programming issue (I imagine that is why it was closed) but it is not. It is simply about how one can find out which process is accessing a particular file on Linux. It has also been answered quite correctly (`lsof`).

I can understand if the question was closed because it was [cross-posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72517/22222) on U&L but in that case, it should be closed for the correct reasons and a comment explaining why cross posting is [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101) added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is better suited on U&L AND it's already cross posted, therefore the close reason is valid.  It shouldn't be migrated since it's already cross posted, so the only reasonable thing to do was close it as off-topic.

You can add a comment yourself to the question if you feel explanation needs to be done, but asking the moderators or community to comment on every question they handle is just too much to ask.

Comment: Fair enough, I just realized that the mod in question chose "off topic" as an easy way of closing the question. I just don't want to give the impression that *nix questions are unwelcome here. But you're right, the mod just chose the easiest way to close and I am nitpicking.

Comment: I think people understand [that *nix questions](http://superuser.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D+OR+%5Bunix%5D+OR+%5Bcentos%5D+OR+%5Bubuntu%5D+is%3Aquestion) are very welcome here.