# Flag as off topic - move to linux/unix community is missing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, off-topic

I have tried to flag [ALSA stopped working with default device](https://superuser.com/questions/819527/asla-stopped-working-with-default-device) as off-topic, to move it into Unix & Linux community.

However there is no option for that (or I don't see it?):

[image]

**Is this missing on purpose?**

I know there is Linux tag in here, but I would move that anyway, because people probably can get better Linux support on that other site.

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644/migrating-questions-to-the-ubuntu-or-linux-unix-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 4):

The majority of questions that are on-topic for Unix & Linux would also be on-topic for Super User. The community there is more specialized and may be better equipped to handle Linux-related questions, but you should remember the general rule that **if a question is on-topic for this site, it should not be migrated to another site (even if it would be better there) unless the OP requests it.**

The right thing to do is to post a comment like this:

> While your question is on-topic for Super User, you may get better answers on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). If you so wish, you may post your question there and then delete it here, or flag your question for migration. Please don't cross-post, though—having the same question on multiple sites at the same time is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

Why would that be off topic? 99% of any Linux/Unix question would be on topic for Super user...

Comment: But that makes Unix & Linux community useless and now I want to ask why Unix & Linux community exists?

Comment: For specifics. Overlaps exist between sites, but there's also Ask Ubuntu (which is Linux-based), Ask Differently (Apple products), Windows Phone (which is also a computer, but a mobile), Server Fault (which is for higher-end systems acting as a server), etc.

Comment: Well, some splits or overlaps make sense (like serverfault community, that conentrates server admins and targets specyfic user type). Apple is very specyfic group of users too. But for mentioned Ubuntu/Linux/Superuser it doesn't make sense for me. Sorry. I just don't agree with split like this. I just splits users randomly.

Answer (score 3):

they possibly could get better support there, but:

- There is a lot of overlap at different SE sites, so migrations should have purpose beyond a OCD organisation.
- It still fits here, and the User didnt do anything wrong, so if they choose to do something stupid within the rules :-) it is thier problem.
- flag and close really bad and really problematic stuff, so that stuff does get dealt with, and the mod peoples are not inundated with stuff that is "ok" , and they can do other cool things like answer more questions.  And users are not frustrated by the site, making more happy people , who stick around.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense for me than Canadian Luke answer.