# Why is this question best suited for Superuser instead of Sharepoint SE?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

When I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1430969/sharepoint-block-users-from-creating-new-lists-or-libraries), I flagged it the moderator(s) because I thought (and still think) that it is best suited for Sharepoint SE. However, the flag was denied.

My question is simple: why is the question best suited for Superuser instead of Sharepoint SE?

Comment: What question are you referring too?  Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, forgot to enter the link. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 7):

It might be better suited there, but it was asked *here*.

Unless a question is specifically off topic here then there is no reason to push it around the network and potentially  alienate users by forcing them to work out where they end up, logging into a new site and so on.

If the user were to flag their question themselves then it would probably be migrated straight away, barring the question being explicitly off topic on the target site.

If you want to give them a gentle nudge then perhaps a comment along the lines of

> Hi, this question might get more attention at our sister site [Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). Rather than simply repost there you can flag your question and ask the moderators to move it for you, or you can delete your question here and re-ask it there. If you would rather your question stayed in this community then that's fine too. Welcome to Superuser!

For more information see [Migrating questions to the Ubuntu or Linux/Unix Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644/migrating-questions-to-the-ubuntu-or-linux-unix-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Valid points made +1. What happened if the OP will get quicker answer(s) on the other site but the question remains here because it was asked here first?

Comment: Then sadly they might have to wait... hence if you feel really strongly that they should ask on the other site you can comment. Just be gentle, they're not wrong asking here, it just might be better elsewhere.

Comment: Will do. If by tomorrow, the question has not received much attention. I will follow your advise.