# Is it proper to invite directly in the tag excerpt users to post elsewhere?

Tags: discussion

**Is it proper to invite directly in the tag excerpt the users to consider to post elsewhere?**
For what I read [[1](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1308/superuser-vs-unix-linux-vs-ubuntu/4357#4357),[2](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4394/when-should-questions-be-moved-to-askdifferent-askubuntu),[3](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1572/do-we-want-to-have-an-option-to-migrate-to-askubuntu),[4](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to?lq=1)...] it seems we should not.

In the Ubuntu tag one on SU, in this moment, is reported:

> A free, open-source operating system based on Debian GNU/Linux. **You may want to consider asking** on https://askubuntu.com/.

I'm specifically thinking about a new user that is reading the excerpt to understand its scope.

If this is proper shouldn't be written too **when** to go on askubuntu or **when** on Unix & Linux **when instead** to post here?

Comment: That is just the tag summary. The reset of the tag includes: "There is [a Stack Exchange site dedicated to Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), which is also a good place to ask any Ubuntu-related questions **if you can't find an answer on Super User.**"

Comment: This is what I (and mainly any of the users) see with a mouse-over event (over the tag), on the [page](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) that appears when I click on the tag.  The full wiki page was seen about 500 times in the last 5 years meanwhile the excerpt it's for sure seen more time, since there are ~13000 questions so tagged. It's a similar situation in the ubuntu-server tag.  Ps> (Thanks for the SE-SU fixing @DavidPostill).

Comment: I think it is indeed proper.  But when it is not proper is entirely based on the case itself.  In other words "it depends" on the specific tag except.

Comment: @DavidPostill However I think is not proper too to write so. It seems we say Ubuntu users are not welcome here.

Comment: @Ramhound So we are only kindly invite to reconsider the SU choice in favour of AskUbuntu (when you try to use that tag).   if it even was, we should at least  say __when__ it is better to go. (And why not to remember even Unix&Linux one?) Consider even that there are many _not "native English speakers"_ , and google translator/chrome translate in some other languages simply  __"it is suggested to"__.

Comment: @Hastur - **It is only a suggestion.**  **ALL** questions about Unix, Linux, and Ubuntu are on topic here.

Comment: @Ramhound This is the point. __We suggest to go elsewhere and it's all__. We do not add __WHEN__ to go there, we do not say __but here is ok__. The message is __Ubuntu users go home__ :-) even if we do not want.

Comment: You are reading into what is being said.  I suggest just reading what is said.  As pointed out we are limited to what can be said in the summary ( length ) the current summary is valid.  We do suggest that questions specifically about Ubuntu might get more attention and higher quality answers there.

Comment: @Ramhound: You do not say __specifically__. You say __generically__ go there. Why for Windows we do not suggest  "You may want to consider asking to microsoft technical center" ?

Comment: @Hastur - Because there is no such thing as "Microsoft technical center", even if there was, it wouldn't be a SE website.

Comment: While I don't have any comment to this tag, I'm glad that [tag:android] tag has site recommendations, because mobile-related question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Generally just because another site exists that covers a subset of Super User doesn't make all **of** that subset found **on** Super User **no** longer welcome or wanted.

Related to migrations, most are not migrated unless the asker themselves prefer to shift the target audience.

**To** clear **up** any implicit "go somewhere else instead and don't bother here" tone, it's been reworded **to:**

> Free, open-source operating system based on Debian GNU/Linux. Ubuntu questions are on topic here, but if you prefer an Ubuntu-only audience there is AskUbuntu.com.

With **the** tag info page expanding on it slightly with:

> The related Stack Exchange site, AskUbuntu, exists if you would prefer an Ubuntu-only audience, as opposed to the multi-environment/operating system one found here on Super User.

Which should better reason why a user may want to consider the other **site.**

Comment: The "A" could be removed along with the "Free, open-source operating system based on Debian GNU/Linux." part of the excerpt supposedly as is the style that never stops being talked about

Comment: I appreciate your intervention. Especially the part about _"as opposed to the multi-environment/operating system"_. Don't worry I will not do here a _querelle_ about the style or the grammar. Not here. :-)

Comment: The question It's about the __multi-environment nature__ of this site. I really like it. Today Win7 40k, Linux 32.4k, Wind 29.4k,Osx 16k, network 16k, Ubuntu 13k questions. An harmony of balanced tones. I think that __to write only for Ubuntu and not for Apple and Windows that there are other__  _"fundamentalist"_ mono system places out of there __is the same then to break this balance__. (I refer not only to sisters on the stack exchange network, but even to Microsoft itself).

Comment: There is no Microsoft SE website though.

Comment: I **like** how this **answer** incorporates **subtleties** of the question **in** focus