# Superuser vs Unix/Linux vs Ubuntu - revisited

Tags: discussion, migration, scope

10 years ago at the time of writing, this question was asked:

[Superuser vs Unix/Linux vs Ubuntu](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1308/122798)

regarding the distinction and overlap of scope between the three StackExchange website.

The accepted answer emphasized how things were in flux:

> Until those sites come out of Beta, the option is really open at this point. Right now we still welcome Ubuntu/Linux questions, and since the sites may get merged before they are out of beta, SU will still be the most visible point since it is actively indexed and open.

Well, the sites have graduated and enough time has passed to pose the question again.

So, in 2020, what is an appropriate rule of thumb...

- for **choosing where to ask** among the three websites (for an issue which might fit on at least two of them, considered separately)?
- for **migrating new questions** between the websites?

Note: I'm *not* asking about migrating questions a good while after they've been asked (which is the subject of [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644/migrating-questions-to-the-ubuntu-or-linux-unix-stack-exchange-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: Honestly I think your question is a duplicate of https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2644/migrating-questions-to-the-ubuntu-or-linux-unix-stack-exchange-sites?r=SearchResults&s=1|31.1809 which was asked a year later than that one. Each site has overlap yes, but different goals and spirits, the only reason to migrate is if asked by OP because they didn't get an answer here. There certainly isn't a reason to be actively trying to push people away.

Comment: @Mokubai: The question you linked to is about migrating _existing/older_ questions, which is a very different thing.

Comment: The question itself *maybe* has that implication, but it applies just as equally to new questions. We have no reason to treat them any differently.

Comment: @Mokubai: 1. That comment could be an answer 2. Even you were right, there's still the question of where to choose to ask.

Comment: 1. My comment is an answer on the duplicate. 2. That is in the other answer on the duplicate...